# What is oracle format for last .0 in TO_DATE ('2020-04-01 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.TZR')?

Tags: java, oracle, date-formatting, to-date, str-to-date

I got this date from Java and is date type.

So trying to format it in oracle

```
select TO_DATE ('2020-04-01 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.TZR') from DUAL
```

not able to format last .0 in date. Tried various way

```
.TZR
  TZR
```

Not sure how to format that? If i remove .0 and .TZR then things work fine.

I am getting following error:

> ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format
>   01820. 00000 -  "format code cannot appear in date input format"

Comment: DATE data type doesn't have fractional seconds and timezone, you need to use TIMESTAMP. To keep it simple you could use the ANSI literal which uses a fixed format. See documentation for datetime literals https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I do not need timestamp actually. I just want to either ignore .0 or omit the same. The type will be date for all

Comment: If you want to stick to TO_DATE, then get rid of `.0` from the input and in the format mask remove `.TZR`. DATE data type can only store date and time portion till seconds only. It could be simply `DATE '2014-04-01'`

Comment: It seems you have got a `java.sql.Timestamp` and applied its `toString` method. The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so first see if instead you can get an `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. Next send one of those into your database rather than a string so you don’t need any conversion on the SQL side.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: What is .0 at end? and any oracle equivalent for same?

Comment: As I already said, .0 is the fractional seconds part. Read the documentation link I provided above. DATE cannot have anything beyond seconds, TIMESTAMP can store fractional seconds and timezone values.

Comment: Ok So i do this :( -> select TO_DATE (REPLACE('2020-04-01 01:00:00.0','.0',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual

Comment: `REPLACE('2020-04-01 01:00:00.0','.0','')` can be simplified to `'2020-04-01 01:00:00'`

Comment: @fatherazrael That would work. But it would be better if you get it as DATE or TIMESTAMP from the Java application itself than manipulating the literal in SQL.

Comment: "*I got this date from Java and is date type.*" - you should retrieve and store DATE values through `java.time.LocalDateTime` (or at least `java.sql.Timestamp`)  **not** as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.0` is fractional seconds, not a timezone offset; but the date data type doesn't allow either anyway.

If your string always has `.0` then you could treat that as fixed characters to ignore it:

```
select TO_DATE ('2020-04-01 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS".0"') from DUAL;

TO_DATE('2020-04-01
-------------------
2020-04-01 00:00:00
```

If it might be non-zero or just if you prefer it can convert to a timestamp and then cast that to a date:

```
select CAST( TO_TIMESTAMP ('2020-04-01 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS DATE) from DUAL;

CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('
-------------------
2020-04-01 00:00:00
```

The `FF` format model element represents fractional seconds, and [as the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A), that is "Valid in timestamp and interval formats, but not in DATE formats".

It isn't entirely cleat what getting the value from Java means, but if you're making a JDBC call and passing the parameter as a string you should step back and use the proper JDBC data type instead. Also note @Ole's comment about using a modern Java datatype if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Such format can be easily converted by type info before

> SELECT timestamp'2020-04-01 01:02:03.4' from DUAL

and **to_timestamp** can also be used in select stmt.